# Conversion of Parquet file format to sequence file format

Tags: hive, parquet, sequencefile

I have my hive tables stored as Parquet format in a location in HDFS. Can I convert the parquet files in this location to Sequence file format and build hive tables over it?
Is there any procedure to do this conversion?

Comment: Why?............

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz some other team in my company want the data as sequence file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new sequence file table and reload data using insert select:

```
insert into sequence_table
select * from parquet_table;
```

Comment: let me try it. Thank you.

Comment: if my sequence table is partitioned by year, month, day then how can I insert all the records from my parquet table which is partitioned by year, month, day as it is into my sequence table?

Comment: create partitioned table, `insert overwrite table sequence_table partition (year, month, day) select from parquet table`, partitions keys should be last, add distribute by partition keys at the end to reduce pressure on reducers. If the target table has exactly the same structure you can select *.

Answer (score 1):

```
hive> create table src (i int) stored as parquet;
OK
Time taken: 0.427 seconds
hive> create table trg stored as sequencefile as select * from src;
```

---

**For @AndyReddy**

```
create table src (i int) 
partitioned by (year int,month tinyint,day tinyint)
stored as parquet
;

create table trg (i int) 
partitioned by (year int,month tinyint,day tinyint)
stored as sequencefile
;

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
;

insert into trg partition(year,month,day)
select * from src
;
```

Comment: if my sequence table is partitioned by year, month, day then how can I insert all the records from my parquet table which is partitioned by year, month, day as it is into my sequence table? Just do insert into?